# Add values to exsisting of a hash

Tags: r, hash

how can one insert additional values to an exsisting key of a hash in R.

```
h=hash()
h[key1] = "value1"
. ???
h[key1] = exsisting values + "value2" = c(values(h),"value2")
```

??

Comment: Presumably you are using the `hash` package, because `hash()` is not part of base R. If this is the case, you should state that in your question (e.g. by using `library(hash)`).  Also, have you read the `hash` package manual?

Comment: Is there a option to separate the values in the hash with a soecial character?

Answer (score 4):

First of all it may be useful to indicate why you want to use `hash` in the first place. Standard R contains a dataformat `list` which is also a key - value store. Unless there is a very specific need to use a different system, the system with list is well documented and has many useful functions like `lapply` which may not exist for your package.

You seem to want to create what is called a [multimap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap) in C++. There is no need to use hash for that, you can do it by nesting lists Eg:

```
h<-list()
h[['key1']]<-list("value1")
h[['key1']]<-list(unlist(h[['key1']]),'value2')
str(h)
List of 1
 $ key1:List of 2
  ..$ : chr "value1"
  ..$ : chr "value2"
```

If your values have the same datatype you don't even need the nested list:

```
h<-list()
h[['key1']]<-"value1"
h[['key1']]<-c(h[['key1']],'value2')
str(h)
List of 1
 $ key1: chr [1:2] "value1" "value2"
```